# Show that a Rule is Derivable in a Hilbert Calculus

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, solution-verification, hilbert-calculus

Is my answer to the following question correct?

> Discuss whether a rule of "partial generalization", i.e. $\frac{H(x)\rightarrow Gx}{\forall x H(x) \rightarrow \exists x Gx}$ is derivable as an inference rule in the Hilbert-calculus.

*Answer*: Assume that

(1) $\Sigma \vdash_H H(x) \rightarrow G(x)$, such that x does not occur free in $\Sigma$. Then, by universal generalization,

(2) $\Sigma \vdash_H \forall x( H(x) \rightarrow G(x))$. Now, by Axiom 4 and Modus Ponens, it follows that

(3) $\Sigma \vdash_H \forall x H(x) \rightarrow \forall x G(x)$. Application of the Deduction Theorem yields

(4) $\Sigma , \forall x H(x) \vdash_H \forall x G(x)$. But as

(5) $\forall x G(x) \vdash_H \exists x G(x)$ is a rule in $\vdash_H$,

(6) $\Sigma , \forall x H(x) \vdash_H \exists x G(x) $ follows by (4) and (5) via the Rule of Cut. Repeated application of the Deduction Theorem yields the desired result:

(7) $\Sigma \vdash_H \forall x H(x) \rightarrow \exists x G(x) $. ∎

---

*Note*: I made use of the following theorems, axioms and rules, which are all free to use for this exercise:

Universal Generalization in the Hilbert Calculus: $\frac {H}{\forall v H}$ (such that if H is deduced from $\Sigma$, then v must not occur free in $\Sigma$.

Axiom 4 of the Hilbert Calculus: $\forall v (H_1 \rightarrow H_2) \rightarrow (\forall v H_1 \rightarrow \forall v H_2)$

Deduction Theorem: $\Sigma , H \vdash G$ iff $\Sigma \vdash H \rightarrow G$

Rule of Cut: $\Sigma \vdash C, \Delta \cup {C} \vdash H \Rightarrow \Sigma, \Delta \vdash H$

I also presuppose (5) as an evident rule.

Comment: The issue is with step 5); if you want a formal proof within a specified proof system, you have to use axioms and rules of the calculus plus already proved results. Thus, you have to prove 5).

Comment: It seems that your system has no axioms and rules for existential quantifier; maybe it is defined as $\lnot \forall \lnot$...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I looked it up in my textbook and (5) is an already proven theorem. Shouldn't it be correct then?

Comment: @frabala If there is no x that is G, shouldn't at least in classical logic $\forall x G(x)$ be false? $\forall x G(x)$ requires all members of the domain to be G. So it suffices that only one member is not G, a fortiori if no member is G.

Comment: Yes, it's fine.